# What happens without server_name matching but localhost is specified

Tags: nginx

hostname1 and hostname2 represent the same host running nginx. How request is passed when user visits hostname2:80 on another machine?

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    # other content
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hostname1;
    # other content
}
```

Comment: In the absence of a `default_server`, the first `server` block will be the default. [This link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) should help you.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes! Thanks.